# Volumetric effects not working

Tags: texturing, volumetrics

I have a black hole, and the accretion disk is a volumetric, however when I added noise to the density there wasn't any result. This is what I want: [image: source: Space Engine General Relativity Update]

vs what I have:[image]

This is my node setup: [image]

Comment: It's hard to know for sure without seeing your node setup, but volumetrics often benefit from being heavily clamped using a ColorRamp. Also remember that although a Noise Texture _technically_ operates in the 0-1 range (which it does), 98% of its "working values" fall within the .25-.75 range, so you may want to also consider using a Map Range node set to that range.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I’ve got both a colour ramp and map range. It goes Noise>Colour Ramp>Map Range

Comment: Are you using Cycles or EEVEE? Also, could you post a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: Cycles, I attempted to post the blend file but that hasn’t worked, I’ll post the node setup

Comment: It’ll be hard to read, since there’s so many nodes

Comment: @ChristopherBennett after a bit of experimenting I discovered when I unplug the density node and turn it to 0 nothing changes